# how do I save the parsed data to a file

Tags: ruby, file, save, nokogiri

I wounder how I can save the parsed data to a txt file. My script is only saving the last parsed. Do i need to add .each do ? kind of lost right now

here is my code and if maybe somebody could explain to me how save the parsed info on a new line

here is the code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.clearsearch.se/foretag/-/q_advokat/1/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css(".gray-border-bottom").each do |item|
  title = item.css(".medium").text.strip
  phone = item.css(".grayborderwrapper > .bold").text.strip
  adress = item.css(".grayborder span").text.strip
  www = item.css(".click2www").map { |link| link['href'] }

  puts "#{title} ; \n"
  puts "#{phone} ; \n"
  puts "#{adress} ; \n"
  puts "#{www} ; \n\n\n"

  puts "Writing"
  company = "#{title}; #{phone}; #{adress}; #{www} \n\n"
  puts "saving"
  file = File.open("exporterad.txt", "w") 
  file.write(company)
  file.close
  puts "done"
end
puts "done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `File.open` inside your loop truncates the file to zero length with each invocation. Instead, open the file outside your loop (using the block form):

```
File.open("exporterad.txt", "w") do |file|
  doc.css(".gray-border-bottom").each do |item|
    # ...
    file.write(company)
    # ...
  end
end # <- file is closed automatically at the end of the block
```

Comment: ahh, so everytime i need to loop through something I will first open the file and then loop through and then write. 

perfect and alot of thanks to you